# Mapping URLs to files in nginx

Tags: nginx

In config file,

```
location /i/ {
    root /data/w3;
}
```

The `/data/w3/i/top.gif` file will be sent in response to the `/i/top.gif` request. How can I set it to ignore `i` in file paths? Indeed I need `/i/top.gif` to be mapped to `/data/w3/top.gif`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `alias` instead `root` and remove the `/` after the i. 
It should look like this

```
location /i {
     alias /data/w3;
}
```